# UIImageView displaying in wrong dimensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm loading an `UIImage` into a `UIImageView` and setting the dimensions of the image to be the same as of the `UIImageView` which was created in storyboard and is 60x60 by default. Code-wisely, everything works, the debug says that the dimensions of image and imageView are both 60px, however looking at the simulator, you can obviously see a rectangle rather than a box. Where is the problem?

Image loading code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/TheOfficialKanyeWest/picture?"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userImageURL]];
    UIImage* profilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    profilePic = [self imageWithImage:profilePic scaledToSize:profilePictureImageView.frame.size];
    [profilePictureImageView setImage:profilePic];
    //[profilePictureImageView sizeToFit];

    NSLog(@"\n\nView:\nWidth: %f\nHeight: %f\n\nImage:\nWidth: %f\nHeight: %f\n", profilePictureImageView.frame.size.width, profilePictureImageView.frame.size.height, profilePic.size.width, profilePic.size.height);
}
```

Custom function for resizing image:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Also, the debug I put in the `ViewDidAppear` gives me:

```
View:
Width: 60.000000
Height: 60.000000

Image:
Width: 60.000000
Height: 60.000000
```

Edit:
Forgot to add screenshot

[image: screenshot]

**Solution**

The code was absolutely fine. I failed to notice that my automatic constraints were causing the imageView to resize to the odd rectangular shape. I added my constraints manually and now it works well.

Comment: add screenshot of simulator.

Comment: do you have any constraints applied to imageView ?

Comment: nikhil84 - thanks for the comment, I forgot to show you what I was seeing

harsha - Yeah, the imageView was created in storyboard so I applied the automaticconstraints to keep it in this position irregardless of the resolution

Comment: then did you pin width and height of the imageView using constraints to 60 X 60 ?.

Comment: set 60x60 constraints instead of automatically set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin **width** and **height** constraints of the `imageView` to 60 and 60 in story board don't use automatic constraints.

Comment: are you using any size classes ? If not pinning the things should definitely work out. can you show us the constraints applied ?

Comment: I don't know what that is so I suppose I do not

Comment: When I was first trying your method, I just applied extra constraints to fixate the height and width to 60. Now, I tried removing all the constraints as you said and adding them manually and the image is scaled properly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code, in coding its absolutely right, but in storyboard there is any mistakes in autolayouts..[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move the code from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear`. In `viewWillAppear` your `UIImageView` is not set to its final frame.

Comment: When I did that, I still see the same thing as displayed on the screenshot, however the debug code now says that the width and height of both image and imageView are 60 & 127 respectively

Comment: Which means you are not setting your ImageView to 60x60 in storyboard. It is 60x60 in storyboard but is changing on device. Edit your autolayout values.

Comment: I applied additional size constraints to the storyboard constraining the width and height to 60, and when I inserted `NSLog()` before I even start to load the image to check the size of the view, and the view is 60 * 127.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code in

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
// put your code to here to set frame and size of imageview.
}
```

Comment: add this line 
 profilePictureImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;